# Topological Proof of Infinite Primes

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}$ had the topology where every arithmetic sequence is open. Each arithmetic sequence is also closed. I showed that every non-empty open set is also infinite.

My question is in the final step where I have to show that the set of integers not in the sequence of multiples of primes ${-1,1}$, is not open and hence there are infinitely many primes. I don't see how the connection is made between ${-1,1}$ being not open and infinitely many primes.

Comment: What does ‘the sequence of primes $\{-1,1\}$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each arithmetic sequence is closed.
Finite unions of closed sets are closed.
Thus, if there were only finitely many primes, $\{-1,1\}^{c} = \cup_{p\in\mathbb{P}} p\mathbb{Z}$ would be closed. 
Then $\{-1, 1\}$ would be open.
However, $\{-1, 1\}$ is not open. Therefore, the set of prime numbers cannot be finite.